# Wcf CommunicationObjectFaultedException c#

Tags: c#, wcf, app-config

i got this exception

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectFaultedException' occurred in
>   System.ServiceModel.dll

when i try this code

```
        using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(WcfProductService)))
        {
            host.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("server is open");
        }
```

on app.config i defin the url like

```
   <endpoint address="http://localhost:9999/ProductSercie" binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="" contract="IWcfProductService.IWcfProductService"
        name="ProductServiceEndPoint" kind="" endpointConfiguration="" />
```

i serach on this problem and try to add this url on cmd with netsh but not success
look https://i.snag.gy/50tRok.jpg
what can i do please?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your ServiceHost object is disposed right after you open it, because host.Open() is asynchronous.
Try this, for example:

```
    using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(WcfProductService)))
    {
        host.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("server is open");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```